How to handle double quotes in a call to the Microsoft Graph API endpoint to search emails based on 'from' field
I am trying to search emails from a certain person in my inbox via MS GRAPH API in ASP.NET.
This is my C# code to construct the REST URL:
(i am trying to search all emails where the 'from' field contains 'greet')
sRestURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/USER@MAILBOX.COM/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$search=\"from:\"greet\"\"&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=Id eq \'LONG 0x0E08\')&$count=true";

However, the backslashes around the value of the search parameter are giving me a headeach...
How can I get rid of the backslashes highlighted here below in yellow?

Because when I send above URL to MS Graph API  I get statuscode 'BadRequest' due to the backslashes around the search value.

When I do the post via GRAPH EXPLORER, without the backslashes, everything goes fine:

Thanks
Frederik

Solved:
sRestURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/MAILBOX/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=Id eq \'LONG 0x0E08\')&$count=true&$search=\"from:\\\"greet\\\"\"";

